# Javascript DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript

Hello, is there any way when my script outputs an image can i make it output a bootstrap row instead? I need 3 rows and 4 columns in each:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        // IMAGE HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        // IMAGE HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        // IMAGE HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

I need there to be 4 rows holding 3 images per row which I am struggling to get my head around. Here is my javascript code so far, if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

```
function displayContent() {

    document.getElementById("findCar").onsubmit = function() {

        var registration = document.getElementById("regPlate").value,
            reference = document.getElementById("stockRef").value;

        var regArray = registration.split(''),
            refArray = reference.split(''),
            referenceNinth = refArray[10];

        var reverseReg = regArray.reverse();
        var obfuscated = [];
        var obf_index = 0;

        for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
            obfuscated[obf_index] = refArray[i];
            obf_index++;
            obfuscated[obf_index] = reverseReg[i];
            obf_index++;
        }

        obfuscated.push(referenceNinth);

        var obfuscatedString = obfuscated.join("");
        var camera = [];
        var cameraSize = "350";
        var cam_index = 0;

        for(i=0; i<=1; i++) {
            if(i>0) cameraSize = "800";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/f";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/i";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/6";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/5";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/4";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize+"/r";
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i];
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

    return false;

    };
}
```

Comment: Do you want 3 rows of 4 columns or 4 rows of 3 columns? I couldn't figure it out for my edit

Comment: I need 3 rows with 4 columns in each sorry. Thanks for your help so all in all there are 12 images.

Comment: Where do those 12 images come from? Are they static or from some kind of AJAX call? Edit - nevermind, I read your code properly I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You could build up an html string in your loop and then append using `.innerHTML`.

e.g. - replace your final for loop with something like:

```
var newHtml = '<div class="row">';

for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {

    newHtml = newHtml + '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                        '<img src = "' +
                        'http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/' + obfuscatedString + '/' + camera[i] + '"></img>' +
                        '</div>';
}

newHtml = newHtml + '</div>';

document.getElementById("#IdOfElementToAppendTo").innerHTML = newHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I tried your code but it did not work :(, I have tried this sort of code numerous times and for some reason it does not seem to work